# Deleting multiple resources during a single request in a RESTful service

Tags: rest

I'm looking for examples of how others have created a RESTful service that supports deleting multiple entities of the same type in a single request.  For example if I were writing an email service I may want to be able to delete multiple messages at the same time.

One way to handle this could be have a resource that is defined as "a collection that contains the mail items identified by the specified id values".  This resource could have the following interface:

GET /api/mail/1;2;5;38 - return the collection of items
DELETE /api/mail/1;2;5;38 - delete the collection of items

Is this a common way of handling multiple deletes?  What are some other ways people have seen this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels a little odd because the RESTful URI doesn't name a "resource", but rather a collection of resources.

While it feels a little odd, I think there are no better ways to specify that kind of "collection".

We do things like that also -- some of our path levels are "ranges" or "sets" or "filter functions".

```
/path/to/resource/in:filter;filter;filter/
```

Comment: I guess I think of a collection of resources as a resource itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can define a new resource that represents a collection of the resources that have been marked for deletion, and then delete that resource to delete them?